# Случайная строка

Tags: python

Парни помогите написать функцию, которая возвращает случайную строку заданной длины.

Строка должна состоять из больших и маленьких латинских букв и цифр.

```
def get_random_string(length: int) -> str:
  pass
```

Ограничения:

Не использовать модуль `string`

Не создавать руками список `['a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0, 1, ..., 8, 9]`

Comment: chr(65) это A. 
chr(97) это a.
Ну и дальше по порядку.

Comment: Ну можно не руками, можно циклами создать этот список. В частности пользуясь функциями `ord` и `chr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random, base64

def get_random_string(n):
    return base64.b64encode(random.randbytes(n//8*6+6)).replace(b'+', b'A').replace(b'/',b'B')[:n].decode()
```

Comment: как это запринтить? не пойму.

Comment: кажется не работает

Comment: работает. научитесь выполнять функции...)

Comment: Нет все нормально, работает)) допустил ошибку и пока заметил ее. спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример функции, которая удовлетворяет указанным требованиям:

```
import random

def get_random_string(length: int) -> str:
    # Создаем пустую строку
    s = ""
    
    # Перебираем диапазон от 0 до length
    for i in range(length):
        # Выбираем случайный символ из диапазона ASCII-кодов
        # от 65 (А) до 122 (z), включая как буквы латинского алфавита
        # так и цифры
        c = chr(random.randint(65, 122))
        
        # Добавляем символ в строку
        s += c

    # Возвращаем сгенерированную строку
    return s

# Генерируем случайную строку длиной 10 символов
s = get_random_string(10)
print(s)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, у вас еще генерит символы еще, о них не говорилось в задании, может не подойти,